# why is it valid to use the name of the array as subscript to an int literal

Tags: c, arrays

As the title suggests, why is this valid and correct?

```
int main(void)
{
    int a[10];
    a[5] = 22;

    // Prints 22, similar to what a[5] would print.
    printf("%d", 5[a]);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Three easy steps, converting the array to a pointer:

1.) `a[x] == *(a+x)` **:** An Array operation is the same as a pointer-offset addition
2.) `*(a+x) == *(x+a)` **:** Addition can be reversed
3.) `*(x+a) == x[a]` **:** pointer-offset addition can be converted back to array notation.

Comment: Very nice how you make a flow from the popular `a[x]` to his question! And how you show how you get there! (From my perspective almost a question to protect :D )